# Unable to close quick action from LWC (from Web component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-events, quickaction

I'm directly using LWC component in the Quick Action through flow, once the submit button is called I'm dispatching an event from LWC but aura is not capturing and also Quick action modal is not closing.

Here is the code:

LWC

```
closeModalQuickAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('closeQuickAction'));
    }
```

Aura :

```
<aura:component implements ="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" >
    <c:dynamicInputTable oncloseQuickAction="{!c.closeModal}"/> 
</aura:component>

({
    closeModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("closing the popup");
        
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

this is how I'm doing but nothing is happening

Comment: At a guess, have you tried `onCloseQuickAction` instead of `oncloseQuickAction`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't have Capital Letters in event name. Change `closeQuickAction` to either `closequickaction` or `close_quick_action` and it should work, sometimes LWC doesn't show it as error, but it'll never work with capital letters